# Separating tag attributes as a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

My entry (The variable is of string type):

```
<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>
```

My expected output:

```
{
'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/',
'rel': 'nofollow ugc',
'text': 'wiki',
}
```

How can I do this with Python? Without using beautifulsoup Library

Please tell with the help of lxml library

Comment: use `lxml` instead of `beautifulsoup`

Comment: you could try to use `regex` but it can be very complex task in some situations so better use `beautifulsoup`, `lxml` or similar modules.

Comment: @Curiouskoala That's right, thanks for helping me get to the answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I am sorry for your opinion. I tried for almost 2 days but did not get the result and then I asked a question.

Comment: @Sardar So where is the code that you tried? You need to include that in your question so that people can understand where you're going wrong.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski My code could have caused the question text to become cluttered. To ask a clear and short question, it is better if my code is not in the question. This clear and short question made me get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with lxml (**but without bs!**):

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = '<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>'
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
print(root.attrib)

>>> {'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': 'nofollow ugc'}
```

But there's no `text` attribute.
You can extract it by using `text` property:

```py
print(root.text)
>>> 'wiki'
```

To conclusion:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = '<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>'
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
dict_ = {}
dict_.update(root.attrib)
dict_.update({'text': root.text})
print(dict_)
>>> {'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': 'nofollow ugc', 'text': 'wiki'}
```

**EDIT**

-------regex parsing [X]HTML is deprecated!-------

Solution with regex:

```py
import re
pattern_text = r"[>](\w+)[<]"
pattern_href = r'href="(\w\S+)"'
pattern_rel = r'rel="([A-z ]+)"'

xml = '<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>'
dict_ = {
    'href': re.search(pattern_href, xml).group(1),
    'rel': re.search(pattern_rel, xml).group(1),
    'text': re.search(pattern_text, xml).group(1)
}
print(dict_)

>>> {'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': 'nofollow ugc', 'text': 'wiki'}
```

It will work if input is string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no way to get text with the help of lxml library?

Comment: @Sardar you can read official page [parsing html with lxml](https://lxml.de/parsing.html). I took all info from that.

Comment: @Sardar, author of this response, and other people reading this: You **do not** parse HTML with regex, ever: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ Of course, marking this answer as accepted only adds insult to the injury.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire Thank you for your important point. i use the lxml library and i do not parse HTML with regex

Comment: You're right! But someone suggested that it could be parsed by re... It is just a try for a **very** special situation. Anyway I wrote a solution by lxml lib.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>'''
root = etree.fromstring(html)
attrib_dict = root.attrib
attrib_dict['text'] = root.text 
print(attrib_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': 'nofollow ugc', 'text': 'wiki'}
```

Answer (score 1):

While using `BeautifulSoup` you could use `.attrs` to get a `dict` of of a tags  attributes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="https://wikipedia.org/" rel="nofollow ugc">wiki</a>')
soup.a.attrs

--> {'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': ['nofollow', 'ugc']}
```

To get also the text:

```
...
data = soup.a.attrs
data.update({'text':soup.a.text})
print(data)

--> {'href': 'https://wikipedia.org/', 'rel': ['nofollow', 'ugc'], 'text': 'wiki'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You can tell with the help of lxml library?

Comment: This is solution with BeautifulSoup which deprecated by author of question :) Via bs it will be easy to unpack any lxml constructions by using some magic lambda functions.

Comment: @vovakirdan: You are right, to fast while reading - So just see it as example in addition, if somebody comes across.