# Extract link from string

Tags: python, html, string, extract

I am currently trying to find out the way how to efficiently extrant substrings from my file in Python.
I have a file with extracted html code

```
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-OJVLA-20220624132548.pdf" target="_blank">Jitka Horáková</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-XUBIC.pdf" target="_blank">Bohumil Tobolka</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/5/Zivotopis-UNBLA.pdf" target="_blank">Stanislava Rousová, Ing.</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-NYBCF-20220407134152.pdf" target="_blank">Ladislav Macháč</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf" target="_blank">Dana Macháčová</a></td>
```

but mostly I am failing with extraction. My goal is to have another txt file with extraxted clear link "/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf" without HTML syntaxes. Means strast with /archiv and ends with .pdf

I tried to explore for each method and regex, but not so lucky since I am begginer. I would be happy for any advice.

Comment: The way you do this is with an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.  You then look for all of the `<a>` tags and extract their `href` attributes.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73374424/17845381 Maybe dublicate.

Comment: Note: **NEVER USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML/XML**. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/17845381

Answer (score 0):

Use the `urllib.parse.urlparse` function to parse the URL. Here's an example:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url_str = 'https://example.com'
url_obj = urlparse(url_str)

if not (url_obj.scheme and url_obj.path): # validity check
  print(f'The URL {url_str} is invalid!')
else:
  print(f'The URL {url_str} is valid!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular python we can do this easily without any libraries:

```
text = """
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-OJVLA-20220624132548.pdf" target="_blank">Jitka Horáková</a></td>
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-XUBIC.pdf" target="_blank">Bohumil Tobolka</a></td>
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/5/Zivotopis-UNBLA.pdf" target="_blank">Stanislava Rousová, Ing.</a></td>
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-NYBCF-20220407134152.pdf" target="_blank">Ladislav Macháč</a></td>
<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf" target="_blank">Dana Macháčová</a></td>
"""

links = [line.split('<a href="')[1].split('"')[0] for line in text.split('\n') if '<a href="' in line]

print(links)
```

The output:

```
['/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-OJVLA-20220624132548.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-XUBIC.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/5/Zivotopis-UNBLA.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-NYBCF-20220407134152.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf']
```

What this does is split the file by '\n' and then returns the text between the quotes in the href= section for each line. It creates an array called 'links'

To write the array to a file, with each link on one line:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
for link in links:
    f.write(link + '\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall can help....

t = '''

<td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-OJVLA-20220624132548.pdf" target="_blank">Jitka Horáková</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-XUBIC.pdf" target="_blank">Bohumil Tobolka</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/5/Zivotopis-UNBLA.pdf" target="_blank">Stanislava Rousová, Ing.</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-NYBCF-20220407134152.pdf" target="_blank">Ladislav Macháč</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf" target="_blank">Dana Macháčová</a></td>

'''

print(re.findall(r'\/archiv.*?pdf', t))

['/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-OJVLA-20220624132548.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/6/Zivotopis-XUBIC.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/5/Zivotopis-UNBLA.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-NYBCF-20220407134152.pdf', '/archiv/zivotopisy/2022/4/Zivotopis-PVDPA.pdf']
```